Errors in postman when querying a gRPC service running in a docker container
TLDR:> I cannot get postman to successfully query a gRPC service running in a docker container.
I have C#/dotnet server with gRPC endpoints.   When I run my server locally (aka in desktop shell), I am able to use postman to make a gRPC call and successfully get the expected response.   (see screen shot)
However, when I try using postman to query the same server running in a docker container it fails with error Operation cancelled.  (see screenshot)
my docker compose file is built like this:
version: '3.8'
name: boot_node
services:
  boot-node:
    container_name: boot-node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: boot_node.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50051:50051"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    networks:
      - ironbar-network

networks:
  ironbar-network:
    driver: bridge

and my docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /node_dir

COPY ./src ./src

WORKDIR /node_dir/src
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /node_dir/bin

EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 50051 

WORKDIR /node_dir/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "node.dll"]

It looks like the ports are properly available
d:\engineering\dotnet\ironbar\src\node>docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                                                               NAMES
2ab951699288   boot_node-boot-node   "dotnet node.dll"   23 minutes ago   Up 6 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50051->50051/tcp   boot-node

I have tried:

turning off firewall
in place of localhost, used 10.0.0.106 and  host.docker.internal (from my hosts file)
in place of localhost, used 172.18.0.2 which is the ip address given to the boot_node_ironbar-network found from docker inspect  (this gives me a 14 unavailable error)
reviewed my work to this source link

I think I have posted everything relevant. The entire code base can be found on github.
Is it possible to use postman to query a gRPC service running in a docker container?  if so, what is wrong that I cannot successfully call the service?

I'm not a .NET developer but I suspect (!) that you're container's entrypoint (dotnet node.dll) is binding to localhost rather than 0.0.0.0. When you run the container, I assume there are no errors logged and you can see the port if you ss --tcp --listening --processes | grep 50051 but what happens if you telnet localhost 50051?

Built your project and there's an error logged Now listening on: http://localhost:50051 (so that is one issue as the port doesn't extend beyond the container). There are other errors regarding HTTP/2 is not enabled for 127.0.0.1:8080. The endpoint is configured to use HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, but TLS is not enabled. HTTP/2 requires TLS application protocol negotiation. Connections to this endpoint will use HTTP/1.1. (unsure why 8080!?) but that may also be an issue. gRPC requires HTTP/2 and so won't work over HTTP/1.1 but should be possible (insecure over HTTP/2)

the tls errors are easy for me to turn off.  I missed the error about listening on 50051.  looking...that might be the problem.  I am using Kestrel and calling ListenLocalHost.

@DazWilkin  Thank you.  That was it.  I changed my kestrel implementation and now it receives/handles queries in both local environment and in the docker container!  Turns out my docker image was good, I guess :) it was code after all.

I'm pleased to hear it's working!

The solution was to change how I setup Kestrel listening on the gRPC port.  I needed to be listening to 0.0.0.0 (any) not localhost.
EG:
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrelOptions =>
{               
    kestrelOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, configurationOptions.RPCPort, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
});

